# Notions of infinity in $\mathsf{ZF}$ without choice

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Consider the following statements about a given set $X$ in in $\mathsf{ZF}$:

(1) There is $x_0\in X$ such that there is a surjective map $\varphi: X\setminus\{x_0\}\to X$.

(2) There is an injective map $\iota:\mathbb{N}\to X$.

It is easy to see that (2) implies (1) in $\mathsf{ZF}$, but are they equivalent?

Comment: Oh yeah, I just realized where I learned this from: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/104913/on-surjections-idempotence-and-axiom-of-choice should this be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: Now the question has changed and I removed my comment. With this version, the answer is no, as is shown in Asaf's answer.

Comment: (2) is strictly stronger than (1), but equivalent to the dual version of (1) ("1-1 map from $X$ into $X\setminus \{x_0\}$").  The dual version of (2), on the other hand (surjection from $X$ onto $\omega$) follows from (1) but is strictly weaker

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent.

It is a nice theorem that if there exists an infinite Dedekind-finite set (which is a set which satisfies the negation of (2)), then there is one which satisfies the first condition.

If $D$ is a Dedekind-finite set, then $S(D)$ which is the set of all injective finite sequences from $D$ is also Dedekind-finite (because the sets are injective, every collection of them is uniformly enumerated, so if there was a countable infinite set of these sequences, their union would be a union of uniformly enumerated sets, which would be a countably infinite subset of $D$).

Now simply consider the projection from $S(D)\setminus\{\varnothing\}$ onto $S(D)$ where you remove the last coordinate of the sequence.

---

You might be interested in the following paper:

> Truss, J. **Classes of Dedekind finite cardinals.** *Fund. Math.* **84** (1974), no. 3, 187–208. [PDF](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm84/fm84119.pdf)

In which the author takes seven definition of finiteness (proposed by Azriel Levy) and investigates the relations between them. Your first condition is one of the properties considered there.